# Turning a for loop function in Vectorized form with numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy, dataset, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to make my program faster with the use of numpy arrays however all the time I have tried modifying the vanilla python in the form of vectors it has given me errors. How can I vectorize the code so that I dont have to use the for loop.In the for loop code down below I have the linear regression and standard deviation formulas that are dependent on the `PC_list` values to be calculated.

```
PC_list= [457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000]

#x_mean and x_squared is used for the lin regressions and stand dev
x_mean = number/2*(1 + number)
x_squared_mean = number*(number+1)*(2*number+1)/6

for i in range(len(PC_list)-number):

    y_mean = sum(PC_list[i:i+number])/number   
    xy_mean = sum([x * (i + 1) for i, x in enumerate(PC_list[i:i+number])])/number

    #Linear regression slope(m) and b vert shift
    m = (x_mean* y_mean- xy_mean)/((x_mean)**2- x_squared_mean)
    b = y_mean - m*x_mean

    #Standard Dev function = square root((first list value - y_mean)+(second list value - y_mean) + (third list value - y_mean)/n-1)
    std = (sum([(k - y_mean)**2 for k in PC_list[i:i+number]])/(number-1))**0.5

    #Upper and lower boundary calculations 
    Upper_Boundary = round((m*(i)+b + Upper*std),1)
    Lower_Boundary = round((m*(i)+b + Lower*std),1)

    #appends the upper and lower boundary to a list
    upper.append(Upper_Boundary)
    lower.append(Lower_Boundary)
    
    
    #Boundary x and y positions appended in list for graphing
    Boundary_x = number + i
    Boundary_x_list.append(Boundary_x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good implementation of simple linear regression with Python and Numpy here: [Simple Linear Regression in Python](https://letsfigureout.com/2021/01/05/simple-linear-regression-in-python/)

The first thing I would recommend is converting your original dataset to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])

# Calculating mean of the array is made trivial
x_mean = X.mean()

# values of array are squared first and then we get the mean
x_squared_mean = np.power(X, 2).mean()

# covariance (b)
cov = np.sum((X - x_mean) * (y - y_mean)) / np.sum(np.power(X - x_mean, 2))

# variance (m)
variance = x_mean - (cov * x_mean)

# regression line
reg_line = cov + variance * X
```

This is just an example, but in general the first step is to convert your data to numpy arrays and then you get access to all the non-loop type functions that are implemented in C.

Comment: Thank you for the code, however I am a bit confused on how you got the  `y` and `y_mean` values.

Comment: The y values were just placeholders, you didn't include your y array in the original example so I just assumed it existed somewhere in your code. The same principal would apply to the y array, convert it to a numpy array first then the code above will apply.